# convert pandas dataframe to list and nest a dict?

Tags: pandas

I have a list:

```
l = [{'level': '1', 'rows': 2}, {'level': '2', 'rows': 3}]
```

I can conert to DataFrame, but how do I convert back?

```
frame = pd.DataFrame(l)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have `to_dict`

```
frame.to_dict('r')
Out[67]: [{'level': '1', 'rows': 2}, {'level': '2', 'rows': 3}]
```